# How can i store diffrent images to my list using C#?

Tags: c#, image, list

I have a problem as follow:

I basically have a code that generates a series of bitmap images. At the end of each iteration I use:

I was expecting that after all the iterations being completed, I end up with a new list which is consisting of different images. However I just realised that in my list-1 only the same image is going to be copied again and again.

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  Please show us where you're adding items to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me if I am making any mistake in my code?

You likely need to make a *new image* for each loop iteration in the "code that generates a series of bitmap images" (in the code you're not displaying).

If you reuse the same image (the `bmp` variable), without creating a new image, (ie: `bmp = new Bitmap(width, height)` or similar), you'll end up overwriting and reusing the same image in memory for each loop iteration, which explains your current behavior.